# Three.js property length of geometry.vertices is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello people of StackOverflow.
I'm learning three.js and as a learning project, I chose to make an 80's style retro hills similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/LivelyWallpaper/comments/h8l0x8/the_hill_wallpaper_customisable/).
Everything was going smoothly but then

```
script.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at init (script.js:37)
        at script.js:6
```

appeared.
I checked everywhere but found no solution.
This is my script.js(html is just the default template for head and body).
Any help helps!

```
let renderer;
let scene;
let camera;
let mesh;

init();
animate();

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
    scene.add(camera);

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 256, 256);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xc04df9, wireframe: true });
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    floor.rotation.x = 90;
    const verticeXYZ = geometry.vertices;
    //perlin.seed()
    for (let i = 0; i < verticeXYZ.length; i++) {
        verticeXYZ.x = 53;
    }
    scene.add(floor);
}
```

Error appears at line 37:

```
for (let i = 0; i < verticeXYZ.length; i++) {
        verticeXYZ.x = 53;
    }
```

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? I have the same issue. It seems that some geometries doesn't have vertices field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is more like a pure Javascript error. The constant `verticeXYZ` is not defined, this means `geometry.vertices` is not defined as well. This results in "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when doing `verticeXYZ.length` because there is no `length` property.

Take a look at [this example](https://danbri.org/2011/hoodwink/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain_fog.html) and [its code](https://github.com/rollup/three-jsnext/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain_fog.html). Here, `geometry` is well defined. I recommend you using it as your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?
I guess the vertices property no longer exists in the latest versions.
I used r70 version and it solved my issue.

Comment: and how do you get the vertices now?

Comment: I followed after the suggestion here, and it worked for me.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-geometry-vertices-is-undefined/3133